# How to set zoom level of IE to 100% using python _winreg

Tags: python, selenium, winreg

I am trying to do UI testing and trying to set IE zoom percentage as 100% during run time.

This is what I have tried till now

```
from _winreg import *
"""POC to fix Zoom value to 100 percent"""
keyVal = r'Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Zoom'
key = OpenKey(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, keyVal, 0, KEY_ALL_ACCESS)
SetValueEx(key, "100000", 0, REG_DWORD, 0)
```

Comment: IE should start default with zoom percentage as 100%. How did you landup with the deviation?

Comment: @DebanjanB  -I want to create a setup script which can set IE zoom level to 100% before running my UI  Test-cases on IE browser.

Comment: `setup script which can set IE zoom level to 100%` shouldn't be a _usecase_ itself to be validated rather it's [**Required Configuration**](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver#required-configuration) to set up the _Internet Explorer Driver_.

Answer (score 0):

You can simulate the pressing Ctrl+ 0 , it will set the browser zoom level to 100

```
body = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//body")
body.send_keys("u'\ue009'"+"u'\ue01a'")
```